# Any good alternative to qgis libraries in python

Tags: python, maps, coordinates

I would like to be able to visually graph coordinates just like you can do with [qgis](http://qgis.org/) but without all the hassle of using that python library, something more straight forward maybe?

Comment: "Visually graph coordinates" is a very vague specification of a use case, just as "without all the hassle" is a vague constraint on a desired answer. Consider making your question more specific to avoid it being closed as a shopping recommendation.

Comment: UNM Mapserver has Python Mapscript bindings but if it fits the bill is relative to what you understand as a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem with QGIS? Daniel J. Lewis has prepared a nice writeup about Python mapping: http://danieljlewis.org/2010/09/15/drawing-maps-with-python/ As your focus seems to be just to graph things, especially descartes might to be worth a look: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes/1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of shapely and the Matplotlib pylab module as Sean Gillies does in this [post](http://sgillies.net/blog/995/plotting-gis-shapes/). Shapely can be found on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

```
x, y = geom.xy
pylab.plot(x, y)
```

Make sure to also checkout [Fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona) (nicer ogr byndings for Python).
You might also want to ask the same question on http://gis.stackexchange.com